# How should I set up redirects from http://foo.com to http://www.foo.com

Tags: multi-domain

When users come through the root level of the domain, ie: http://foo.com, I want them to be redirected to http://www.foo.com

How should I go about doing this?

#### Sample .htaccess-file

Thanks to @HendrikEng for his help and clarification. Based on what he said and what I found at https://www.hashtagerrors.com/blog/the-perfect-htaccess-file-for-craft I'm using this .htaccess file. Feel free to copy.

The reason I am redirecting to a specific domain instead of using @HendrikEng's suggestion is that I am running in a multi staging environment (at Hyperlane), and needed to avoid redirects to www. when running on their development or staging environments.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]

    # Add https://www to beginning of URL 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]    

    # Mime types
    # Audio
    AddType audio / ogg .oga ogg
    AddType audio / mp4 .m4a.f4a.f4b
    # Video
    AddType video / ogg .ogv
    AddType video / mp4 .mp4.m4v.f4v.f4p
    AddType video / webm .webm
    AddType video / x - flv .flv
    # Images
    AddType image / x - icon .ico
    AddType image / webp .webp
    AddType image / gif .gif.GIF
    AddType image / jpeg .jpeg.jpg.jpe.JPG
    AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz
    # Fonts
    AddType application / vnd.ms - fontobject .eot
    AddType application / x - font - ttf .ttf.ttc
    AddType font / opentype .otf
    AddType application / x - font - woff .woff
    # JAVASCRIPT
    AddType application / javascript .js.jsonp
    AddType application / json json
    # Extras
    AddType text / x - component .htc
    AddType application / xml .rss.atom.xml.rdf
    AddType application / x - chrome - extension .crx
    AddType application / x - opera - extension .oex
    AddType application / x - xpinstall .xpi
    AddType application / octet - stream .safariextz
    AddType application / x - web - app - manifest + jsonp .webapp
    AddType text / x - vcard .vcf
    AddType application / x - shockwave - flash .swf

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    # Perhaps better to whitelist expires rules? Perhaps.
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
    # cache.appcache needs re-requests in FF 3.6 (thanks Remy ~Introducing HTML5)
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest       "access plus 0 seconds"
    # Your document html
    ExpiresByType text/html                 "access plus 30 minutes"
    # Data
    ExpiresByType text/xml                  "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml           "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/json          "access plus 0 seconds"
    # Feed
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml       "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/atom+xml      "access plus 1 hour"
    # Favicon (cannot be renamed)
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon              "access plus 1 week"
    # Media: images, video, audio
    ExpiresByType image/gif                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg                "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/webm                "access plus 1 month"
    # HTC files  (css3pie)
    ExpiresByType text/x-component          "access plus 1 month"
    # Webfonts
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf    "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/opentype             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff   "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"
    # CSS and JavaScript
    ExpiresByType text/css                  "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript    "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
   RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "(\.(bak|config|sql|fla|psd|ini|log|sh|inc|swp|dist)|~)$">
   Order allow,deny
   Deny from all
   Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule php5_module>
    php_value session.cookie_httponly true
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really `Craft` related, but assuming that you use `.htaccess`  you could set up rewrite conditions to redirect the request:

```
# Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine On

# force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# force www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.foo.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Hey, yeah! You're right. It's not Craft-related. I ended up using .htaccess too. Not tested it in production yet -but Hyperlane- which is my hoster, seems to be using the .htaccess file. A little learning curve for one who's spent much of his life in the Microsoft world ;-)